# How to dump time in format hh:mm:ss to txt file

Tags: python

I have a Python application which can be assumed as a clock. I would like to save all the time into a .txt file while the application is running. For example:

```
12:12
12:13
12:14
...
...
```

I have the code down below but it saves the last second instead of saving all the time:

```
data_line = "{0}\n".format(tm_time)

with open("test1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(data_line)
```

Comment: Open the file in append mode open("test1.txt", "a")  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: see my answer below. in your free time go to this link [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: You can try to search "File Open Mode" on google to understand what's difference between "a" and "w", you can also know all file open modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating document use 'append' mode `open('test1.txt', 'a')`. In this mode you can add new lines to the end of exists document or to blank if doesn't exists. For saving dates in specified in question format use `strftime('%H:%M\n')` where `%H` - hours, `%M` - minutes. For more detail about dates formatting please check next [article](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
data_line = tm_time.strftime('%H:%M\n')

with open('test1.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(data_line)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explaineed why this is a good answer and it seems to be an appbreviated version of the answer by @Adam

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Thank's for a comment. I tried to explain my answer in more details by editting it.

Answer (score 0):

For saving time in special format (or your desired format) you can use the strftime python standard module which covers this needs and beyound. please take a look at this modue in python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime). As we can see strftime accepts specifiers after the `%` character. `Y=year, m=month, d=day, h=hour, m=minutes, s=seconds.`

```
from datetime import datetime

t_format = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")
data_line = "{0}\n".format(t_format)

with open("test1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(data_line)
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.